# Combining CSV files column-wise

Tags: python, ubuntu, csv, memory-management, merge

Suppose I have two CSV files called `A` and `B` in `Python`.

`A`'s `head` looks like:

```
 headerNameA1,headerNameA2
 1.12412424,1
 1,1
 1,1
 1,1
```

`B`'s `head` looks like:

```
 headerNameB1,headerNameB2
 1,1
 1,1
 1,1
 1,1
```

My objective is to combine the two into a file `C`. However, my objective is also **not to load them into RAM** since they're large files. The resulting `C` would be:

```
 headerNameA1,headerNameA2,headerNameB1,headerNameB2
 1.12412424,1,1,1
 1,1,1,1
 1,1,1,1
 1,1,1,1
```

Bonus points if the solution can combine multiple CSV files. However, it is *fine* if this is not possible in the solution since I can always combine whatever else with `C` to make `D`, then combine whatever else with `D` to make `E`, ad infinitum.

The solution can be `Python` based or `terminal` based through `os.system` in `Python`.

Comment: So are you looking for a Python version of `paste -d , f1.csv f2.csv`?  If so, have you looked at the `csv` module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consume one line at a time from both files, concatenating them together and writing to your outfile.  The `csv` module makes things a bit cleaner.

```
import csv
with open('A','rb') as f1, open('B','rb') as f2, open('out.csv','wb') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    r1,r2 = csv.reader(f1),csv.reader(f2)
    while True:
        try:
            writer.writerow(next(r1)+next(r2))
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

And as @RogerPate points out, you can make this slicker with `itertools.izip` (just `zip` if you're in python3)

```
from itertools import izip
import csv
with open('A','rb') as f1, open('B','rb') as f2, open('out.csv','wb') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for r1,r2 in izip(csv.reader(f1),csv.reader(f2)):
        writer.writerow(r1+r2)
```

Comment: for r1, r2 in itertools.izip(csv.reader(f1), csv.reader(f2)): writer.writerow(r1 + r2)

Comment: @RogerPate nice.  Adding that.

Comment: You do not want to import izip as zip, and if you fallback to the builtin zip, it will behave quite differently.  (Though the fallback is unnecessary – itertools is part of Python.)

Comment: @RogerPate I'm fully aware that python2's `zip` operates differently, and I did in fact want to import izip as zip.  There is no `izip` in python 3.  i.e. it's an `ImportError` - thus the try/except.

Comment: If it's unclear, the intent of doing it that way is to make the code agnostic to whether it's run on python2 or python3.

Comment: Writing source so it runs identically (without 2to3 or similar) in 2.x and 3.x is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @RogerPate well as a general philosophy, sure, don't do it in your production code.  But for this example code it serves nicely, so we'll just have to disagree on how universal that "futility" is.

Comment: Example code that isn't meant to be used isn't an example. You would be better served by using itertools.izip and adding a comment "renamed to 'zip' in 3.x", or vice versa. That's shorter, more understandable, and it's much harder to incorrectly use a comment than a bad example.

Comment: Note that there are differences in how csv files should be opened between versions (`'wb'` in 2, `'w', newline=''` in 3) so it's more troublesome than it may seem.

Comment: How do I append the columns to an existing `out.csv` instead of making a new `out.csv`?

Comment: @user2763361 open `out.csv` in `'ab'` mode instead of `'wb'` mode.

Comment: @roippi Would I then use `writerow` still?

Comment: @user2763361 yes.  It just starts writing at the end of `out.csv`.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to respect comma separation. The final file has the first row as `"headerNameA1,headerNameA2,headerNameB1,headerNameB2"` with the quotation marks, instead of just `headerNameA1,headerNameA2,headerNameB1,headerNameB2` without quotation marks.

Comment: @user2763361: It sounds like you want to use your previous output file as one of your input files on the next run.