# Appending two CSV files column-wise

Tags: python, bash, csv, io, append

Suppose I have two CSV files called `A` and `B` in `Python`.

`A`'s `head` looks like:

```
 headerNameA1,headerNameA2
 1.12412424,1
 1,1
 1,1
 1,1
```

`B`'s `head` looks like:

```
 headerNameB1,headerNameB2
 1,1
 1,1
 1,1
 1,1
```

My objective is to take `B` and append it onto `A` so that `A` will then look like:

```
 headerNameA1,headerNameA2,headerNameB1,headerNameB2
 1,1,1.12412424,1
 1,1,1,1
 1,1,1,1
 1,1,1,1
```

From another question I asked, here's code that will take `A` and `B` and combine them into a `C`:

```
 import csv
 with open('A','rb') as f1, open('B','rb') as f2, open('out.csv','wb') as w:
     writer = csv.writer(w)
     r1,r2 = csv.reader(f1),csv.reader(f2)
     while True:
         try:
             writer.writerow(next(r1)+next(r2))
         except StopIteration:
             break
```

However, the objective of this question is just to add `B` onto the back of `A`.

This would be necessary if the size of `A` is such that it is too expensive to disk space to make a copy of it as file `C` before deleting `A` afterwards.

**A bash solution called through `os.system` is acceptable**

Comment: How large are these CSV files that the combined size of them is a concern? Also, the code you have is a strange way of writing `for r1, r2 in izip(f1, f2):` - what's going on with that?

Comment: @JonClements Anywhere between 1 to 10 gigabytes, computations done on a remote server. That was the answer from another question; functions fine so I just leave it.

Comment: @JonClements Apparently I need to use `ab` instead of `wb` but I can't find a guide anywhere

Comment: And the resultant file is also going to be on the remote server? Or are you creating it locally? What is going to be using this file - can that not accept the two files as is... a little more context would be great

Comment: @JonClements `A` and `B` both exist on a remote server. I want to put the columns of `B` into `A` (append), then *after* have `B` deleted. The deletion of `B` later in the process is unrelated to the appending of columns of `B` to `A`. `A` will remain on the remote server. In fact its existence on the remote server is irrelevant. Just pretend that it's all on my local machine..

Comment: Fine - I'm just trying to ascertain if this is something you really need to do... If you're adamant you want to take this approach and run the risk of the updating of `A` failing and then how you go about re-running to take that into account - good luck. I'm thinking more along the lines that depending on how this file is to be used (you didn't include that in your response to my comment), then you keep both files but create "a view" of the two that can be used as the "New A".

Comment: @JonClements I'm open to any approach that doesn't keep multiplying a 10 gigabyte `A` on disk to append a 100 kilobyte file with 3 columns to the end. Conditional on the total size of the folder that all this happens in remains less than 15 gigabytes, I'm open to all possible solutions. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do A and B contain the same number of rows? And are you expecting another update (let's call it C), so that on another run... A should effectively be A + B + C etc...?

Comment: @JonClements Yes to both questions. Around 20 updates for an end file of 20 gigabytes.

Comment: What OS is the server system using?

Comment: Okay then... given the info. then, I've offered a suggestion... it saves disk space at the cost of increased processing... might be suitable for you, might not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining CSV files column-wise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945296/combining-csv-files-column-wise)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with a named pipe. You have a Python process run which creates a pipe and opens it in write mode. It then outputs to that the column wise concatenation of the CSV files (similar to what you've got) already... When another process starts reading that file, it'll be able to consume the data, but no file is actually stored on the server, it's just on demand. When the "file" is consumed, then there'll be nothing in it, and any attempt to access it will block until another process writes to the other end.

Some dummy code - will need more thought out exception handling etc...:

```
import os
from itertools import izip

a = 'abcdef' # File A's rows
b = 'ghijkl' # File B's rows

outname = 'joined'

try:
    os.unlink(outname)
    os.mkfifo(outname)
except OSError:
    pass

with open(outname, 'w') as fout:
    for items in izip(a, b):
        fout.write(''.join(items) + '\n') # Do "real" write here instead...
    os.unlink(outname)
```

Something else opens that "file" in read mode and consumes it to retrieve the data. This should work unless that process has to have "physical files"...

Comment: Do you think this would be slower than making multiple copies of `A` followed by deletions of the old `A`?

Comment: It's at trade-off... What you mention would involve the space and read/write to disk costs to create a new A. While this keeps the storage costs fairly constant, has roughly the same read requirements, but trades the once off disk writes, for the computation costs (which are small) per access....

Answer (score 0):

If you get two file handles for the same file - one in 'read' mode, one in 'update' mode (`r+b`), the same strategy should work.

```
from itertools import izip
import csv
with open('A','rb') as f1, open('B','rb') as f2, open('A','r+b') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for r1,r2 in izip(csv.reader(f1),csv.reader(f2)):
        writer.writerow(r1+r2)
```

When possible I'd recommend against this kind of thing and just explicitly write to a third file.

Comment: Why would you recommend writing to a third file? This is infeasible if one is 10 gigabytes and I need to add lots of small files to it. I do not want to keep creating 10 gigabyte copies for every small file I want to add to the end.

Comment: This solution just removes the first file instead of appending to it.

Comment: I tested this just now on both a Ubuntu box and a windows box, works fine.  As for why it's better to write to a third file: well, just answered that didn't we? If something goes wrong your first file is toast with no way to get it back. Disk space is cheap, you can clean up temp files when you're done.

Comment: The first file being toast is fine for my use case. Are there other reasons? (Not sarcasm, genuinely want to know).

Comment: As a safety I can just count the number of elements in the bottom row versus the top row of the final `A` file. If they are equal then I can assume that it worked properly? If not I can print an error message which is fine (this is not part of a big application I am just scripting here). Would you agree?