# Appending two CSV files together via columns

Tags: bash, ubuntu, csv, io, append

Suppose I have two CSV files called A and B in the folder `/home/user` on `Ubuntu`. What is a command to append `B` to `A`? I prefer a command that doesn't make a copy of `A` but would accept an answer where this preference is not adhered to.

I have already asked for the case of `Python` but this question is **not** about `Python`.

A's head looks like:

```
  headerNameA1,headerNameA2
  1.12412424,1
  1,1
  1,1
  1,1
```

B's head looks like:

```
 headerNameB1,headerNameB2
  1,1
  1,1
  1,1
  1,1
```

My objective is to take B and append it onto A so that A will then look like:

```
  headerNameA1,headerNameA2,headerNameB1,headerNameB2
  1,1,1.12412424,1
  1,1,1,1
  1,1,1,1
  1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Your headings and values don't match up in your desired output -  `1.12412424` should presumably be in the same column as `headerNameA1`

Comment: You asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948526/appending-two-csv-files-column-wise) a little while back.

Comment: @devnull The other question was for `Python`, whose solution would look utterly and absolutely different to the solution to this question. Please reverse your down vote in light of this information.

Comment: Oh, no.  You asked it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945296/combining-csv-files-column-wise) too!  And you were told in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945296/combining-csv-files-column-wise#comment29684196_19945296) that `So are you looking for a Python version of paste -d , f1.csv f2.csv`!

Comment: @devnull No, the second question was about not copying the first file. They're all different questions that seek different answers; over two languages and with two constraints on what happens to both files.

Comment: @devnull It doesn't matter if the answer to this question is in a comment in another question. The other question is different to this question.

Comment: @jkshah So what? If I ask the same question about a null pointer exception in one language and another, these should in my opinion be in separate questions since the answer concerns (a) a different audience, and (b) would likely be quit different.

Comment: @jkshah Perhaps. If it concerns different audiences and the answer will be completely different then yes I think so.

Comment: @user2763361 thanks for your inputs, you may be right but I'm not sure. This motivates me to ask an question on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste` makes it:

```
$ paste -d',' a b
headerNameA1,headerNameA2,headerNameB1,headerNameB2
1.12412424,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
```

The `-d','` part tells paste to use the delimiter `,` (comma).

Comment: What happens to `a` or `b`? Does `b` go inside `a`? Does `b` get deleted afterwards? Or is a third file created in the same directory?

Comment: The result appears on your screen. If you want to save it in a file, then redirect it: `paste -d',' a b > result_file` will save it in the `result_file`.

Comment: Could I do `paste -d',' a b > a` to overwrite `a` with the new file that contains both `a` and `b` appended together?

Comment: No, it will truncate `a` because you cannot use one of the files both as argument as redirection. Try doing `paste -d',' a b > result_file && mv result_file a`. It will output to `result_file` and then move it to `a`, so `a` will end up having the result.

Comment: So did it work to you, @user2763361?

Comment: I'm trying it out now :)